# Validate multiple parameters in JSON Response for a specified range of values

Tags: json, jmeter, assert, jsonresponse

Using JSON Extractor I managed to get the following piece of data which I need to get out of the whole JSON response. Now, I need to validate each field for a range of values for eg. ANNUALINCOME should be between say for eg. 1 - 10 L/annum, AGE 18 - 30 & EDUCATION can be B.A, B.Sc. or B.Com

```
{
:   "ID":"M12345",
:   "EDUCATION":"B.A.",
:   "ANNUALINCOME":"5 - 6 L\/annum",
:   "AGE":"29"
}

mid_10=
{
:   "ID":"M12346",
:   "EDUCATION":"B.Sc.",
:   "ANNUALINCOME":"1 - 2 L\/annum",
:   "AGE":"24"
}

mid_11=
{
:   "ID":"M12347",
:   "EDUCATION":"B.Com.",
:   "ANNUALINCOME":"5 - 6 L\/annum",
:   "AGE":"27"
}
```

Should I be using Response Assertion here? I also need to check which ID's are passed and which are failed. I should ideally be getting the failed ID even if I didn't get the passed ones.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your acceptance criteria are too specific hence you will not be able to use Response Assertion.

You will have to go for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy scripting](http://groovy-lang.org/), example assertion code would be something like:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def income = response.ANNUALINCOME

def lowerBound = (income =~ "(\\d+)")[0][1] as int
def upperBound = (income =~ "(\\d+)")[1][1] as int
def average = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2
def acceptableIncomeRange = 1..10
if (!acceptableIncomeRange.contains(average)) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Annual income is not within the acceptable range: ' + income)
}

def acceptableAgeRange = 18..30
def age = response.AGE as int

if (!acceptableAgeRange.contains(age)) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Age is not within the acceptable range: ' + age)
}

def acceptableEducations = ['B.A.', 'B.Sc.', 'B.Com']
def education = response.EDUCATION

if (!acceptableEducations.contains(education)) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Education is not within the acceptable range: ' + education)
}
```

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for your effort Dmitri, but I am getting Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)

Comment: Most probably regular expression doesn't match the `ANNUALINCOME` value, I cannot help unless I see the valid JSON, not that crap you provided